# TTML+PNG suppont on Chromecast CAF3

Tags: chromecast, google-cast, google-cast-sdk, shaka

I'm migrating from Chromecast v2 framework to CAF3, both using SHAKA player.

On v2 I'm able to activate and watch TTML+PNG subtitles.
On v3 I'm able to activate TTML+PNG but I can't watch them. I've look for a hidden div or something with no luck.

I cant migrate to CAF3 if I'm not able to watch this type of subtitle.

Does any one had a similar issue? Any advice?